# init(ServletConfig config) in webservlet with a entity manager doesnt work

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, entitymanager, init

I have a problem with my **Webservlet**: when I try to initialize my database in NetBeans with an `EntityManager` in the `init(ServletConfig config)` method, glassfish says:

```
    Information:   /file:/C:/Users/Alina/Documents/Uni/Semester 4/SE Projekt/Topfschlag/Rezept/target/Rezept-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_default logout successful
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Information:   /file:/C:/Users/Alina/Documents/Uni/Semester 4/SE Projekt/Topfschlag/Rezept/target/Rezept-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_default login successful
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AnlassBean: [java:global/Rezept/AnlassBean!rezept.ejb.AnlassBean, java:global/Rezept/AnlassBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB RezeptBean: [java:global/Rezept/RezeptBean!rezept.ejb.RezeptBean, java:global/Rezept/RezeptBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AllergieBean: [java:global/Rezept/AllergieBean, java:global/Rezept/AllergieBean!rezept.ejb.AllergieBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB GrundzutatBean: [java:global/Rezept/GrundzutatBean!rezept.ejb.GrundzutatBean, java:global/Rezept/GrundzutatBean]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   Loading application [Rezept] at [/Rezept]
Information:   Rezept was successfully deployed in 657 milliseconds.
Information:   keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 99721694532403200 for application Rezept.
Information:   /file:/C:/Users/Alina/Documents/Uni/Semester 4/SE Projekt/Topfschlag/Rezept/target/Rezept-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_default logout successful
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Information:   /file:/C:/Users/Alina/Documents/Uni/Semester 4/SE Projekt/Topfschlag/Rezept/target/Rezept-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_default login successful
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB RezeptBean: [java:global/Rezept/RezeptBean!rezept.ejb.RezeptBean, java:global/Rezept/RezeptBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AllergieBean: [java:global/Rezept/AllergieBean, java:global/Rezept/AllergieBean!rezept.ejb.AllergieBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB GrundzutatBean: [java:global/Rezept/GrundzutatBean!rezept.ejb.GrundzutatBean, java:global/Rezept/GrundzutatBean]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AnlassBean: [java:global/Rezept/AnlassBean!rezept.ejb.AnlassBean, java:global/Rezept/AnlassBean]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   Loading application [Rezept] at [/Rezept]
Information:   Rezept was successfully deployed in 1.050 milliseconds.
Information:   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Schwerwiegend:   WebModule[/Rezept]StandardWrapper.Throwable
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:161)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at rezept.web.StartServlet.init(StartServlet.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warnung:   StandardWrapperValve[rezept.web.StartServlet]: Allocate exception for servlet rezept.web.StartServlet
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:161)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at rezept.web.StartServlet.init(StartServlet.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know how I can avoid this problem because I need to fill my database before my WebServlet starts.. So this is my code so far:

```
package rezept.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import rezept.ejb.RezeptBean;
import rezept.jpa.Rezept;

import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import rezept.jpa.Allergie;
import rezept.jpa.Anlass;
import rezept.jpa.Grundzutat;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/index.html"})
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {

   // The WebServlet is about a recipe-side which shows you after you clicked on some filters which kind of recipes would fit to your prefernces

   // I need to fill the database first to make some checkboxes...
    @EJB
    private RezeptBean rezeptBean;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);

        // The Syso is to test if the method works...  
        System.out.println("Test string");

        //Fills the "Anlass"-table which means the time you want to eat.. like breakfast, dinner etc..
        List<Anlass> anlässe = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Anlass a ").getResultList();

        if (anlässe.isEmpty()) {
             Anlass anlass; 

             anlass = new Anlass("Frühstück");
             em.persist(anlass);
             anlass = new Anlass("Brunch");
             em.persist(anlass);
             anlass = new Anlass("Mittagessen");
             em.persist(anlass);
             anlass = new Anlass("Abendessen");
             em.persist(anlass);
        }

        //This is to fill and check the ingredients-table
        List<Grundzutat> zutaten = em.createQuery("SELECT z FROM Grundzutat z ").getResultList();

        if (zutaten.isEmpty()) {
             Grundzutat zutat; 

             zutat = new Grundzutat("Eier");
             em.persist(zutat);
             zutat = new Grundzutat("Kartoffeln");
             em.persist(zutat);
             zutat = new Grundzutat("Tomaten");
             em.persist(zutat);
             zutat = new Grundzutat("Mehl");
             em.persist(zutat);
             zutat = new Grundzutat("Nudeln");
             em.persist(zutat);                              
        }

         //to check and fill an allergies-table
        List<Allergie> allergien = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Allergie a ").getResultList();

        if (allergien.isEmpty()) {
             Allergie allergie; 

             allergie = new Allergie("Laktose");
             em.persist(allergie);
             allergie = new Allergie("Weizen");
             em.persist(allergie);
             allergie = new Allergie("Gluten");
             em.persist(allergie);                            
        }                    
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Zuerst Fall-Unterscheidung ob der "Rezepte filtern" oder "Rezepte suchen"-Button gedrückt wurde oder keines von beidem
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action == null || action.equals("")) {
            action="";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/startseite.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);            

        }
```

Has anyone an idea how I can solve this problem? Maybe I can fill my database somehow different but I dont know how...

Comment: Can you provide more of the log file?  It looks like there isn't enough to understand the issue.

Comment: @stdunbar I updated the log file :) hope this helps..

Comment: Try to add the `@Transactional` annotation (`javax.transaction.Transactional`) to your `init()` method.